# Build kernel module in CentOS 7 with changed API

Tags: centos, kernel-module, rhel7

I write NIC module driver and implement it base functions like `ndo_open`, `ndo_stop`, `ndo_start_xmit`...

Sometimes Linux Kernel API is changed in the recent versions. So macro like `LINUX_VERSION_CODE` helps adopt code of the module to recent Linux Kernel versions. In CentOS(RHEL) I meet that function name that changes `MTU` of NIC differs from vanilla Linux Kernel. In vanilla Linux Kernel `v.3.10.0` it prototype is:

```
int         (*ndo_change_mtu)(struct net_device *dev,
                          int new_mtu);
```

But in the `CentOS 7.6.1810 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64` it is:

```
RH_KABI_RENAME(int      (*ndo_change_mtu),
               int      (*ndo_change_mtu_rh74))(struct net_device *dev,
                                                int new_mtu);
```

So I must to use `ndo_change_mtu_rh74` instead of `ndo_change_mtu` which works as I expected.

Is it possible to use some macro to adopt code of the module between different Linux Kernel versions without patching code to prevent compilation errors against CentOS(RHEL) Linux Kernels?

Comment: See https://patches.dpdk.org/project/dpdk/patch/1543265151-14617-1-git-send-email-mgamal@redhat.com/ for an example

Comment: @omajid This is what I need! Please, post your comment as an answer and I apply it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thnk's to @omajid who provides to me topic about [kni: Fix build on RHEL 8](https://patches.dpdk.org/project/dpdk/patch/1543265151-14617-1-git-send-email-mgamal@redhat.com/). The next macro has solved my problem:

```
#if (defined(RHEL_RELEASE_CODE) && \
    (RHEL_RELEASE_CODE >= RHEL_RELEASE_VERSION(7, 5)))
    (RHEL_RELEASE_CODE >= RHEL_RELEASE_VERSION(7, 5)) && \
    (RHEL_RELEASE_CODE < RHEL_RELEASE_VERSION(8, 0)))
#define ndo_change_mtu ndo_change_mtu_rh74
#endif
```